# Show/Hide differents informations in one container by clicking on image : Show informations before hide

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently learning JavaScript and jQuery, and I try to fill a div with some information inside, by clicking on images, like a portfolio.

When I click on an image, the div is filled by specifics information, different for each images, and I show or hide the div, after a click.

When I fill the div with the information of the first image by clicking on it, and I click on the second image, if the first content is still "show", I hide the current, to show the info of the second image.

My problem is, I can see the content of the first image before the toggle's hiding.

NOTE : I'm sorry if it's not really clear, my english is very bad...

NOTE 2 : If this subject was already resolve here, I'm sorry, I searched a lot but did not find anything...

Here's the CodePen : https://codepen.io/benCat/pen/oPdEMm

Here's the code :

```js
var portfolioDescription = {
  toggleDescription: document.createElement("div"),
  contentDescription: document.createElement("div"),

  init: function() {
    var portfolio = document.getElementById("portfolio");

    this.toggleDescription.id = "toggle-description";

    portfolio.appendChild(this.toggleDescription);

    $("#toggle-description").hide();

    this.contentDescription.classList.add("content-description");
    this.toggleDescription.appendChild(this.contentDescription);

    this.content();
  },

  content: function() {
    var self = this;

    $("#click-01").click(function() {
      if (self.toggleDescription.classList.contains("first-active")) {
        self.toggleDescription.classList.remove("first-active");
        $("#toggle-description").hide(1000);
      } else if (self.toggleDescription.classList.contains("second-active")) {
        self.toggleDescription.classList.remove("second-active");

        $("#toggle-description").hide(1000);
        $("#toggle-description").show(1000);

        self.toggleDescription.classList.add("first-active");
      } else if (self.toggleDescription.classList.contains("third-active")) {
        self.toggleDescription.classList.remove("third-active");
        $("#toggle-description").hide(1000);
        $("#toggle-description").show(1000);

        self.toggleDescription.classList.add("first-active");
      } else {
        $("#toggle-description").show(1000);

        self.toggleDescription.classList.add("first-active");
      }

      self.contentDescription.innerHTML = "<p>Test 01</p>";
    });

    $("#click-02").click(function() {
      if (self.toggleDescription.classList.contains("second-active")) {

        self.toggleDescription.classList.remove("second-active");
        $("#toggle-description").hide(1000);
      } else if (self.toggleDescription.classList.contains("first-active")) {

        self.toggleDescription.classList.remove("first-active");

        $("#toggle-description").hide(1000);
        $("#toggle-description").show(1000);

        self.toggleDescription.classList.add("second-active");

      } else if (self.toggleDescription.classList.contains("third-active")) {

        self.toggleDescription.classList.remove("third-active");

        $("#toggle-description").hide(1000);
        $("#toggle-description").show(1000);

        self.toggleDescription.classList.add("second-active");

      } else {
        $("#toggle-description").show(1000);

        self.toggleDescription.classList.add("second-active");
      }

      self.contentDescription.innerHTML = "<p>Test 02</p>";

    });

    $("#click-03").click(function() {

      if (self.toggleDescription.classList.contains("third-active")) {

        self.toggleDescription.classList.remove("third-active");
        $("#toggle-description").hide(1000);

      } else if (self.toggleDescription.classList.contains("first-active")) {

        self.toggleDescription.classList.remove("first-active");
        $("#toggle-description").hide(1000);
        $("#toggle-description").show(1000);

        self.toggleDescription.classList.add("third-active");

      } else if (self.toggleDescription.classList.contains("second-active")) {

        self.toggleDescription.classList.remove("second-active");
        $("#toggle-description").hide(1000);
        $("#toggle-description").show(1000);

        self.toggleDescription.classList.add("third-active");

      } else {

        $("#toggle-description").show(1000);

        self.toggleDescription.classList.add("third-active");
      }

      self.contentDescription.innerHTML = "<p>Test 03</p>";
    });
  }
};

portfolioDescription.init();
```

```css
#portfolio {
  display: flex;
}

#toggle-description {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 1em;
}

.content-description p {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="portfolio">
  <div id="click-01">
    <figure>
      <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/250x150/">
    </figure>
  </div>

  <div id="click-02">
    <figure>
      <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/250x150/">
    </figure>
  </div>

  <div id="click-03">
    <figure>
      <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/250x150/">
    </figure>
  </div>

</div>
```

With it, I'm pretty sure you'll understand me (I hope...)

I know it, it's not the best way to do it, so if you want to advise me, please, do not hesitate, I thank you in advance :)

Thank you for reading!

benCat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're having is because of the animations of the toggleDescription div. If you delay the update of the contents of this div, you get the desired effect

Wrap the lines where you update the contents of the div with a setTimeout call:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    self.contentDescription.innerHTML = "<p>Test 01</p>";
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Hello Javi Mollà!
Thank you for that answer!
I tried this before asking and the effect did not please me, but because of you I added a little fade effect, and it works like a charm! Thanks again, you saved me a lot of time :)